# Flash CS4, Inactive buttons

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, adobe, flash-cs4

I have no syntax errors when I run this code. I checked the variables and the functions in the action panel and it works fine. But, when I remove the codes from the action panel, and try to run the .as file nothing happens when I click the button.
Here's my code:

```
package
{
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.text.*;
import flash.display.MovieClip; 



public class U1A4_Sommeil extends MovieClip
{
private var monMessage:TextField = new TextField;
private var maMiseEnForme: TextFormat = new TextFormat;
public function U1A4_Sommeil ()
{
btnSoumettre.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,Calcule);
}

private function Calcule (event:MouseEvent):void
{
maMiseEnForme.font= "Arial";
maMiseEnForme.size = 20;
maMiseEnForme.color = 0xFF0000;
maMiseEnForme.bold = true;

monMessage.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
monMessage.defaultTextFormat = maMiseEnForme;
monMessage.x = 260;
monMessage.y = 260;
monMessage.border = true;

var intAn : int = int(txtAn.text) - int(txtAnNaissance.text);
var intMois : int = int(txtMois.text) - int(txtMoisNaissance.text);
var intJour : int = int(txtJour.text) - int(txtJourNaissance.text);

var strResultat : String = ("Tu es agé de "+ (intAn*365+intMois*30+intJour) + " jours." 
+ "\n" 
+ "Tu as dormi " + ((intAn*365 + intMois*30 + intJour)*8) + " heures"
+ "\n"
+ "depuis ta naissance.");
monMessage.text = strResultat;
addChild (monMessage);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This is a little too vague. Did you try putting a breakpoint at the first line of the Calcule method to see if it is called or not?

Comment: 1st : How did you use the `.as` file ? 2nd : You have to know that you should have the button with text fields in your stage ! 3rd : You can not calculate the difference between two dates like what you did.

Comment: Nothing happened when I put own the breakpoint... does that mean that my use of the .as file is wrong? My .fla file is named U1A4_Sommeil.fla. and the .as file U1A4_Sommeil.fla. They are saved under the same folder and I just open them in flash cs4 and press ctrl+enter to debug and it does nothing. Also, akmozo, what do you mean by button with text field? Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your have just to add your `U1A4_Sommeil` class as your document class using your document properties :

[image]

Or, from **File** Menu > **ActionScript Settings...** then :

[image]

Hope that can help.